# "O melhor método sobrecarregado compatível tem alguns argumentos inválidos"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, método

Estou criando um serviço com um método que tem um argumento do tipo `List<OrdemPais>()`, e passando um objeto desse tipo para o método, porém na hora compilar aparece o erro:

```
O melhor método sobrecarregado compatível com 'Mahikari.Business.Domain.OrdemPaisVigencia.SetOrdensPaises(System.Collections.Generic.List<Mahikari.Business.Domain.OrdemPais>)' tem alguns argumentos inválidos
```

Essa é a parte do código que o método é chamado:

```
protected void salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        SalvarEstadoOrdem();

        List<OrdemPais> OrdemPaisList = new List<OrdemPais>();


        OrdemPaisVigencia.Vigencia = dteVigencia.SelectedDate.Value;

        List<OrdemPais> ordemPaises = new List<OrdemPais>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> ordem in ordens)
        {
            var o = new OrdemPais(ordem.Key, ordem.Value);
            ordemPaises.Add(o);
        }

        try
        {
            OrdemPaisVigencia.SetOrdensPaises(ordemPaises);

            paisService.SaveOrdemPais(OrdemPaisVigencia);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        Response.Redirect("OrdemPais.aspx", true);
    }
```

O método em si:

```
public void SetOrdensPaises(List<OrdemPais> ordemPaises)
    {
        if (ordemPaises.Any())
            this.Validation.Errors.Add(MainResource.Mensagem_ListaNaoPodeEstarVazia);

        this.OrdemPaises = ordemPaises.OrderBy(or => or.Ordem).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: O erro é na compilação ou na execução?

Comment: Compilação, e o mais estranho é que não sinaliza com o sublinhado vermelho embaixo(que normalmente fica no visual studio quando está errado).

Comment: Não consigo identificar nenhum problema vendo só isso. Pode estar me escapando algo. Mas esse código tem várias coisas esquisitas. Sei lá se o problema pode estar sendo causado por alguma outra coisa. Se conseguir fazer um [mcve] pode ser mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Vou colocar o método inteiro desse trecho de código, o que tem esquisito @bigown ?

Comment: É estranho porque tanto a chamada quanto a assinatura _aparentemente_ tem o mesmo tipo. Certifica de que o `OrdemPais` em  `List<OrdemPais> ordemPaises = new List<OrdemPais>();` é exatamente o mesmo em `SetOrdensPaises(List<OrdemPais> ordemPaises)`. 
Quero dizer, se não estão sendo referenciados de DLLs separadas apesar de terem o mesmo nome.

Comment: @EricWu  Era exatamente isso, a classe(que está em outra DLL) tinha o mesmo nome de uma página, por isso dava o erro. Se quiser pode responder a pergunta para eu marcar como resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certifique-se de que o `OrdemPais` em

```
List<OrdemPais> ordemPaises = new List<OrdemPais>();
```

é exatamente o mesmo `OrdemPais` em

```
SetOrdensPaises(List<OrdemPais> ordemPaises);
```

Se eles têm o mesmo nome, mas estão em namespaces diferentes, eles são essencialmente tipos diferentes.